# Taking DNA and printing out Protein regions Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to be reading in a fasta file of DNA strings, which so far I have working. However, I am attempting to only print out segments that begin with ATG and end with either TAA, TGA, or TAG but it is just printing out the entire line from the file. Is there any way to print out the smaller segment within the line? This is what I have so far for code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNAApp
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the full path to the fasta file.");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    File file = new File(input);

    try
    {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner( file );

        while ( fileScan.hasNextLine() )
        {
            String line=fileScan.nextLine();
            line.replaceAll("X", "A");
            if(line.contains("ATG"))
            {
                line.substring(0 + 3);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException fnfe )
    {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

and this is the output I get:

```
Please enter the full path to the fasta file.
C:\Users\Downloads\test.fasta.txt
AACGACGGCGTGCATGCTTGACGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA
CTACAAATCAATGAGCCACCCACTTCAATCGTCAGGAGCATCCTCAGGAA
CGCTACCTTTTGAAAATGATGCATTGAAAAAGGAAATTGCTTTGTACAAG
TCAACTCCTTTAATTTCAAAAAATGATTTAGACTCCTTTGATTTGCTTAA
TAACGTGGATATGACTATCTTCATTGCCTTTAATACTCAAGGTCAAGGAA
GTGTATGGCTTTGAATACTTGGATAAAATCCAATTTGAATTTACTTTCCT
TAAATACAAGAAAGAATGCCAAGAAA

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `line.substring(0 + 3);` does nothing because you're ignoring the return value.

Comment: Find the index of ATG. From that point find indexes of  TAA, TGA, an TAG.  Then take the index of the three with the lowest index number not including -1. From there use the two indexes to create a `substring(firstIndex, lowestIndexOfTheThree + 3);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There should be a better way to find out the lowest out of the three indexes greater than -1 instead of putting those in an array and comparing. Please try this code. None of your lines actually begin with TGA. So, you might want to change it before you start testing. I modified the dna file while testing.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNAApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the full path to the fasta file.");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    File file = new File(input);

    try {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileScan.nextLine();
            line = line.replaceAll("X", "A");
            if (line.startsWith("ATG")) {
                int[] dnaArray = new int[3];
                //Get the lowest index out of TAA, TGA, or TAG
                dnaArray[0] = line.indexOf("TAA",3);
                dnaArray[1] = line.indexOf("TGA",3);
                dnaArray[2] = line.indexOf("TAG",3);
                //We cannot use Math.min, because it will consider -1 as the lowest if it does not find a string with the index passed to it.
                int lowestIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                //We try to find the lowest of all indexes.
                for(int index : dnaArray) {
                    //Check only if the current index is greater than -1 and less than the current lowest index.
                    if(index > -1 && index < lowestIndex) {
                        lowestIndex = index;
                    }
                }
                //Do a substring from the line only if lowestIndex is not equal to the Integer.MAX_VALUE (intial value set
                if(lowestIndex != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                    line = line.substring(0,lowestIndex + 3);
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}